# How can I go back and test where something broke?

Tags: git

I want to go back to prior commits and run my program until I found out where something broke without deleting or affecting my commits. Once I find the last commit where it was working I can see what changed the go back to the current commit and fix it.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You should try using `git bisect`. This functionality allows you to essentially binary search through your commits. You pick a commit when things were still good, and a commit when things are broken, and proceed from there.

Check out this page for a tutorial:

http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch05.html

(Search for "Where Did It All Go Wrong?")

Answer (score 6):

Git provides just the right command for that: `git bisect`. It will perform a binary search and allows you to mark each tested commit either `good` or `bad`

Start the bisect procedure with:

```
git bisect start HEAD <last good commit>
```

Then build your source, run it, check for errors, and finally mark it:

```
git bisect good # or:
git bisect bad
```

If you cannot test a commit (build broken, etc.), skip it with `git bisect skip`.

Do that until you found the first *bad* commit. To get back to your original commit, run `git bisect reset`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to go back some commits to test you can do: `git checkout SHA`