# How can I jump back in my commits without making any changes?

Tags: git

I want to jump to a previous commit with the ability to jump out of it at anytime, not affecting my repo. What would I use to do this in git?

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout with a new branch, so that your current branch can remain unaffected.

Comment: Please do not create duplicate questions. Confirmed diplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389813/how-can-i-go-back-and-test-where-something-broke

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to commit or stash your working tree changes, but you can

```
git checkout <sha1 of previous commit>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with git [checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout.html). But I recommend reading a book about git which explains how you can use git. [Progit](http://progit.org) is a good and free online book.

Comment: Version Control with Git (O'Reilly): http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022862.do is another great resource.  Progit is a good introduction, but I got a lot more out of VCwG.  However, the 2nd edition is due out in August 2012, so if I were looking to buy it again I'd wait for the 2nd edition.